# Custom Meta table does not show components and other columns after upgrade CWA Application to 2011 SP1

Tags: cwa

We have recently upgraded the CWA Application to 2011 SP1. So, as per the documentation, replaced the existing jars and replaced with `cd_tdf.jar` and `cd_cwa.jars`.

Changed the class value in `cd_deployer_conf.xml` with `Deploy` attribute from `com.tridion.profserv.deployer.MetaDataProcessor` to `com.tridion.deployer.Processor`.

Now, publish to Broker DB gets success, but the values in `Custom Meta` is not getting updated correctly. The fields like `components`, `component_templates` and others are getting removed.

Can you please help me here?

Thanks,
Anusha

Answer (score 2):

I understand CWA previously used the Custom Metadata Processor, which adds additional details the the `CUSTOM_META` table, partly based on XML snippets in your Component Templates.

Per the documentation, [this has been deprecated](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_CWA_2011_SP1/concept_6F0DD571D73B4995AA5BC3D21CFA0AED), but can be enabled on the latest version (see the doc link), specifically:

> The metadata processor, which was originally added as a custom
>   Processor in the Content Deployer, is no longer a part of CWA. If you
>   want to continue to use it, you must use the Professional Service TDF
>   module. Even if you use the TDF module, you can no longer use the
>   URLNormalisation setting in the cd_tdf_conf.xml configuration file:
>   you must set its Enabled attribute to false, or remove it altogether

Comment: thanks.. We are still using the Professional Service TDF Module and then it works :)